# Why does my indicator-datetime in Ubuntu 16.4 Gnome shell show no numbers?

Tags: gnome, indicator

[image: no numbers shown in gnome shell panel]

as seen in screenshots, my indicator-datetime in Ubuntu 16.4 Gnome shell shows no numbers?
Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the preferences, go to the Weather Services tab and select Yahoo as the source. For some unknown reason, Open Weather Map isn't working anymore.